# AWK: operations on multiple-columns data filles

Tags: bash, awk, multiple-columns

I am dealing with the analysis of a number of data filles of multiple-colums format by means of the following AWK code (does all stat calculations) integrated into bash script (operates with the data files):

```
#!/bin/bash
home="$PWD"
# folder with the outputs
rescore="${home}"/rescore 
# folder with the folders to analyse
storage="${home}"/results
#cd "${home}"/results
cd ${storage}
csv_pattern='*_filt.csv'


while read -r d; do
awk '
FNR==1 {
   if (n) {                     # calculate the results of previous file
      m = s / n                 # mean
      mean[suffix] = m          # store the mean in an array
      lowest[suffix] = min      # lowest value of dG - correspond to the upper number in the original CSV
   }
   prefix=suffix=FILENAME
   sub(/_.*/, "", prefix)
   sub(/\/[^\/]+$/, "", suffix)
   sub(/^.*_/, "", suffix)
   s = 0                        # sum of $3
   s2 = 0                       # sum of $3 ** 2
   n = 0                        # count of samples
   min = 0                      # highest value of $3
}
FNR > 1 {
   s += $3
   s2 += $3 * $3
   ++n
   if ($3 < min) min = $3       # update the lowest value
}
END {
  if (n) {                     # just to avoid division by zero
   m = s / n
   lowest[suffix] = min
  }
   print "Lig(CNE)", "dG(mean)", "dG(min)"
   for (i in mean)
      printf "%s %.2f %.2f %.2f\n", i, mean[i], lowest[i]
}'  "${d}_"*/${str} > "${rescore}/${str_name}/"${d%%_*}".csv"
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '*_*_*' | awk -F '[_/]' '!seen[$2]++ {print $2}')
```

Basically, while operating in loop, the script calculates for each of the CSV file  the mean value for the numbers in the third column (dG) along with detecting of its minimal value (always corresponded to the line with ID=1):

```
# input *_filt.csv located in the folder 10V1_cne_lig1001
ID, POP, dG
1, 142, -5.6500 # this is dG min
2, 10, -5.5000
3, 2, -4.9500
4, 150, -4.1200 # this is pop(MAX)
```

and saves the results in another multi-column output file (for 10 processed CSVs it countains 10 lines), contained a part of the name of each processed CSV (with corresponded prefix used as the ID of the line), its dG(mean) and dG(min):

```
# output.csv
Lig(CNE) dG(mean) dG(min)
lig1 -6.78 -7.23
lig2 -5.56 -5.76
lig3 -7.30 -8.69
lig4 -7.98 -8.60
lig5 -6.78 -7.16
lig6 -6.24 -6.50
lig7 -7.44 -8.01
lig8 -4.62 -5.60
lig9 -7.26 -7.48
lig10 -5.9 -6.03
```

I need to add a possibility my the AWK part of the code to detect and print in the individual column the values from $3 (dG) that would have the maximum values in $2 (column pop ) of the initial csv. In the above example this value of dG is -4.1200, which is corresponded to the 4th line of CSV based on its highest number(150) detected in the second column.  So the aim is to print to the output.csv the forth column, which will contain the $3 (dG) value corresponded to the maximal value in $2 (pop).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the `awk` portion, would you please try:

```
awk -F ", *" '                  # set field separator to comma, followed by 0 or more whitespaces
FNR==1 {
   if (n) {                     # calculate the results of previous file
      m = s / n                 # mean
      mean[suffix] = m          # store the mean in an array
      lowest[suffix] = min      # lowest value of dG - correspond to the upper number in the original CSV
      highest[suffix] = fourth  # dG of highest pop
   }
   prefix=suffix=FILENAME
   sub(/_.*/, "", prefix)
   sub(/\/[^\/]+$/, "", suffix)
   sub(/^.*_/, "", suffix)
   s = 0                        # sum of $3
   s2 = 0                       # sum of $3 ** 2
   n = 0                        # count of samples
   min = 0                      # lowest value of $3 (assuming all $3 < 0)
   max = 0                      # highest value of $2 (assuming all $2 > 0)
}
FNR > 1 {
   s += $3
   s2 += $3 * $3
   ++n
   if ($3 < min) min = $3       # update the lowest value
   if ($2 > max) {
      max = $2                  # update the highest value
      fourth = $3               # to be printed in the fourth column
   }
}
END {
   if (n) {                     # just to avoid division by zero
      m = s / n
      mean[suffix] = m          # store the mean in an array
      lowest[suffix] = min
      highest[suffix] = fourth  # dG of highest pop
   }
   print "Lig(CNE)", "dG(mean)", "dG(min)", "dG(highest pop)"
   for (i in mean)
      printf "%s %.2f %.2f %.2f\n", i, mean[i], lowest[i], highest[i]
}' *_filt.csv
```

- Setting field separator to `,` will be important. Otherwise numerical comparison may break.
- I have left some unused variables (such as s2) as is, which may be used for your future update plan.

Comment: thank you very much! just one question would  "Setting field separator to , " influence some another calculations that had been made for $3 (e.g calculations of the mean, rmsd etc)?

Comment: The short answer is `no`. The possible problem has become tangible
due to the comparisons between positive numbers today.
Without assigning the field separator to ",", the fields are split
on the default field separator, blank characters, then each field may
contain trailing comma such as `10,` and `2,`.
The comma is automatically chopped off on most arithmetic operations
including the comparison between negative numbers.

Comment: The problem occurs on the comparison between positive numbers such as
`10,` and `2,`. As they look like strings rather than numbers, `awk` try to
perform string comparison between them, which yields `2, is greater than 10,`.
I have missed the potential problem in my previous answer. BTW I have added another modification of the option `-F,` into `-F ", *"`,
which will remove the leading whitespaces of the fields, just in case.

Comment: OK, thank you very much! i am going to run a short benchmark of this update

Comment: just finished test with > 2000 csv filles, so basically ain't no difference using awk -F ", *" '     or awk -F, '   thus indicating that the both versions works perfectly ! Cheers

Comment: Thank you for the meaningful feedback! I do appreciate your great effort.

Comment: Hey, I shall be very thankful if you could depose alitle bit of your time to help me alitle bit more with my AWK quest >> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67436842/awk-a-workflow-for-the-extracting-of-the-information-from-multi-column-files